# How can I put a meta tag in WordPress, without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Where can we put meta tags in our WordPress website without using a plugin?

```
<meta name="description" content="Your description" />
```

Comment: In your header.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the header.php file of your active theme.

Realize that plugins could possibly duplicate the tag or attempt to "unhook" it, so if you hard code values into the meta tag, you may end up with duplicate meta tags or errors.